# Substring SQL With a condition

Tags: java, sql, substring, conditional-statements

I must extract a sub-string but only if a condition is met.
The users in this column must fill the telephone numbers of clients (It's a varchar column),

Some examples of those stored values are:

1. 23==880-3112==9435
2. 52==031    31466==171
3. 321==15850

The '=' are numbers I don't wanna share.

I need to extract the mobile number (The one with the length of 10), but as you can see, those numbers are not stored in the same positions, I can't use a LEFT() or RIGHT() function because of that, some are separated with '-', others with spaces between the house number and mobile number.

If this can't be done with SQL, I'm using Java but I don't even know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I'm using SQL SERVER 2012
The expected results from the examples are

1. 3112==9435
2. 31466==171
3. 312==15850

I want to obtain always the 10 characters number.

Sorry and thanks

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Can you explain what the `=` means? If the `=` is just obscuring numbers from us, you can use arbitrary numbers instead.

Comment: What should happen there?  Some DBMS can use regular expressions, it's important to know if you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL or SQLite or SQL Server, etc, etc.  Could your requirement be rephrased as "extract the last 10 numerals from the string"?    Or do you mean "the first occurrence of 10 consecutive numerals"?  Regular expressions can do either of those, but you haven't told us which DBMS you're using, so we on't know if you have access to regular expressions.

Comment: what exactly are you expected results for example 1,2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String comparison [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Where part of your 1st example will be

```
WHERE TELEPHONE_NO LIKE '23%%880-3112%%9435'
```

---

[Edit]

To extract a substring you can use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('23==880-3112==9435', '-', 10);
    -> '3112==9435'
```

Comment: The OP wants to `extract` a phone number.  Something like selecting the last ten numerals.

Comment: Now only I understand the question :-( Please see the edit. You can use the regular expression to match with space and '-'

Comment: On row 2 it follows a space.  On row 3 it starts straight away.  "Follows a `-`" isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: I tried. but couldn't find a way. we have to use java code.

Comment: Unless the OP has postgreSQL or any SQL dialect that support regular expressions.  But, as the OP isn't responding, I guess the OP doesn't care any more?